# C++ data conversion of user defined object

Tags: c++

In this program we use data conversion from class a to class c.when we use

```
a(c c1)
{
   return (c1.getd()*100)
}
// constructor in class a, this is correct, but when when we use

c(a a1)
{
   return (a1.getb()/100)
}
// constructor, then compile error comming that getb is not a member of a please clear what is the problem.


#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

    class a;
    class c {
       int d;
       public:
          c() {
             d=0;
          }
          c(int x) {
             d=x;
          }
          int getd() {
             return d;
          }
          void putdata() {
             cout<<d;
          }
          c(a a1){ 
             d=(a1.getb()/100);//here is compile error coming --getb is not a member of a
          }
  };
  class a {   
     int b;
     public:
       a() {
     b=0;
       }
       a(int x) {
     b=x;
       }
       void putdata() {
         cout<<b;
       }
       int getb() {
         return b;
       } 
   };

  void main() {
    c c1;
    a a1=100;
    a a2(100);
    c1=a1;

    c1.putdata();
    getch();
  }
```

Comment: Please reformat your code and your question...it's difficult to read

Comment: I think the problem is beacause compiler in no way knows classs A has getb function ... can you defne class a before class C ?? Or is there anyway of declaring it bfrhand ..?

Answer (score 1):

`a` is (forward) declared, but not defined when that function definition is encountered. Move the definition to after the definition of `class a`:

```
class a;

class c {
    int d;
public:
    c() { d=0; }
    c(int x) { d=x; }
    int getd() { return d; }
    void putdata() { cout<<d; }

    c(a& a1); // Pass a1 as reference as class a is not yet defined.
  };

class a
{
...
};

c::c(a& a1)
{ 
    d=(a1.getb()/100);
}
```

Also, `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <iostream.h>`.

Comment: when we do this then same problem comming with the constructor      a(c c1){ retrun c1.getd()*100 in class a i.e. getd is not a member of c

Comment: Did you change the argument type from `a` to `a&`? I just double-checked this and it compliles fine.

Comment: thankyou ,i understand my mistake and this code clear all my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

when you write

```
class a;
```

you are promising that you will define "class a" at a later stage.

You have then used class a before defining it.
The code can be made to work by writing the code that use class a after class a is defined.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class a;
class c
{
    int d;
public:
    c():d(0)         {}
    c(int x):d(x)    {}
    int getd()       {return d;}
    void putdata()   {cout<<d;}
    c(a a1);     // defined after class a is defined

};

class a
{   int b;
public:
    a():b(0)         {}
    a(int x): b(x)   {}

    void putdata()   {cout<<b;}
    int getb()       {return b;}     
};


c::c(a a1)
{
    // uses class a after it is defined
    d=(a1.getb()/100);
}

void main()
{
    c c1;
    a a1=100;
    a a2(100);
    c1=a1;


    c1.putdata();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Happy to be of help. Please go ahead and accept the answer if it cleared your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler always parses your text files from the top, hence before using a method or function you have to define it.

Your line `class a;` tells the compiler that there is a class named a, but at this point, no member functions are known to the compiler.

If you put the following code before the declaration of class c, then the compiler knows that the use of mehod `getb` on an object of class a is not illegal, even though it does not know what the method does.

```
class a
{
    public:
        int getb();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the order in which the classes are declared. Try the following:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class a
{
  int b;

public:

  a()
  {
    b=0;
  }

  a(int x)
  {
    b=x;
  }

  void putdata()
  {
    cout<<b;
  }

  int getb()
  {
    return b;
  }

};

class c
{
  int d;

public:

  c()
  {
    d=0;
  }

  c(int x)
  {
    d=x;
  }

  int getd()
  {
    return d;
  }

  void putdata()
  {
    cout<<d;
  }

  c(a a1)
  {
    d=(a1.getb()/100);//here is compile error coming --getb is not a member of a
  }

 };

int main()
{
c c1;
a a1=100;
a a2(100);
c1=a1;


c1.putdata();
getch();

return 0;
}
```